# Accessing array of child objects in c#

Tags: c#

I am having a scenario like the following in datagridView - CellPaintingEvent

```
object cellValue = e.FormattedValue;
```

through the above sequence  i am getting array of values sometimes 
i.e:

```
cellValue = system.object[];
```

pls let me know how to access all those  child objects value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i tried with cellValue[0], it's not working

Comment: " it's not working" please be more precise! exception? message?

Comment: Please present us with a [mcve] and check the [help/on-topic] pages to ask an ontopic question

Comment: in compile time itself i am getting the issue like "Cannot apply indexing with[] to an expression of type 'object''

Comment: I will recommend a [mre] a simple grid with minimum item. And the event code. We may n,eed the  `ValueType` and `FormattedValueType` anhd those tyupe definition if it's something custom. And FormattedValue return an object not an array. you may need to unbox it. and a `string foo = e.FormattedValue.ToString();`

Comment: @SiddarthVarunesh - None of the code you've shown would produce the error `"Cannot apply indexing with[] to an expression of type 'object''`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, `e.FormattedValue` returns an object [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.formattedvalue). So Op first comment `cellValue[0]` will give this error. And in question `object cellValue`, in comment `cellValue[0]`. But that's not op original issue.

Comment: `callValue` is of type `object`, which knows no such thing as an index-based access. You have to cast to the specfic runtime-type, e.g. `MyType[]`. However I don´t know what `MyType` actually is. You have to ask yourself which types you´re storing in `FormattedValue`.

Comment: @xdtTransform - but the OP hasn't shown the code `cellValue[0]` in his question, hence my comment.

Comment: @xdtTransform, as per my grid e.Value of DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs returns {object[3]} . but when i try to cast that e.Value to an array object, i couldn;'t able to do that cast since e.Value is not array

Comment: Found a solution for this by exposing grid object for my code sequence      **object[] datagridCell =(object[])grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;**

Answer (score 1):

The CellPainting event is for a single cell with a single value. FormattedValue is not an array.
Have you checked the MSDN? They have some examples how to use the event and the DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs:

[DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellpaintingeventargs)

[FormattedValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellpaintingeventargs.formattedvalue)